# How can I map edgeweights from a matrix onto edges along the paths generated by another matrix

Tags: matrix, graphs-and-networks, code-review, code-request

Suppose that we have two matrices with identical dimensions: `matA` and `matB`. I want to identify a set of pathways using `matA`, but then map the respective edge weights from `matB` onto the pathways identified from `matA`. I like to perform this operation with a MMA function such as `map[matA_, matB_, t1_,t2_]:=`

```
ClearAll[n, matA, matB, map];
<< IGraphM`;
<< BoolEval`;
SeedRandom[4];
n = 10;
matA = RandomReal[{0.1, 0.5}, {n, n}];
matB = RandomReal[{0.1, 0.4}, {n, n}];
map[matrixA_?MatrixQ, matrixB_?MatrixQ, t1_Real, t2_Real] := {
selectBetween[t1, t2] = BoolEval[t1 <= matrixA < t2];
subgraphBetween[t1, t2] = 
AdjacencyGraph[selectBetween[t1, t2], VertexLabels -> "Name"];
pindex = FindPath[subgraphBetween[t1, t2], 1, 3, Infinity];
prule=Rule @@@ Partition[pindex[[4]], 2, 1]
Graph[prule, EdgeWeight -> Flatten[matrixB], DirectedEdges->True, VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"]
```

I think everything works fine until `Graph[..]` in the above code. `pindex` is identified but I cannot map the associated edge weights from `matB` onto `pindex`.

Needless to say, any improvement on this `code` is most welcome. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** ***"give different color to source (red) and sink (green) vertices"***

```
ClearAll[map3]
map3[matrixA_?MatrixQ, matrixB_?MatrixQ, t1_Real, t2_Real] := 
  Module[{indices = Union @@ (Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ 
     FindPath[AdjacencyGraph[Map[Boole[t1 <= # <= t2] &, matrixA, {-1}]], 
       #[[1]], #2[[1]], ∞, All])}, 
    HighlightGraph[Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ indices, 
      EdgeWeight -> Extract[matrixB, indices], 
      EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", ##3], {#, #2}]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
map3[matA, matB, .2, .3][{4}, {6}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
map3[matA, matB, .2, .3][Style[4, Red], Style[6, Green], 
 VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexSize -> {4 | 6 -> Large}, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

Maybe something like:

```
ClearAll[map2]
map2[matrixA_?MatrixQ, matrixB_?MatrixQ, t1_Real, t2_Real] := Module[{indices = 
    Union @@ (Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ FindPath[AdjacencyGraph[
       Map[Boole[t1 <= # <= t2] &, matrixA, {-1}]], #, #2, ∞, All])},
   HighlightGraph[Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ indices, 
       EdgeWeight -> Extract[matrixB, indices], EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", ##3], 
     {#, #2}]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[4];
n = 10;
matA = RandomReal[{0.1, 0.5}, {n, n}];
matB = RandomReal[{0.1, 0.4}, {n, n}];

map2[matA, matB, .2, .3][4, 6, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
vLabels = {1 -> AGF, 2 -> CO12, 3 -> MA1, 4 -> MA2, 5 -> EGW, 
   6 -> CST, 7 -> WHS, 8 -> HOT, 9 -> TSC, 10 -> FIN};
map2[matA, matB, .2, .3][4, 6, 
  VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed[v /. vLabels, Center]}, VertexSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
Row[map2[matA, matB, .2, .3][##, ImageSize -> Medium, 
    VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Large] & @@@ 
 {{4, 6}, {1, 4}}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I wanted. Thank you...

Comment: in the above `code` I wanted to use my custom-made vertex labels such as `vLabels = {1 -> AGF, 2 -> CO12, 3 -> MA1, 4 -> MA2, 5 -> EGW, 
   6 -> CST, 7 -> WHS, 8 -> HOT, 9 -> TSC, 10 -> FIN}` but then I receive an error relating to `HighlightGraph`. I tried several different ways to use my own labels with no success. Could you please tell me where to revise in your code?

Comment: @Tugrul, try `map2[matA, matB, .2, .3][4, 6, 
 VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed[v /. vLabels, Center]}, 
 VertexSize -> Large]`? (If it does not work maybe you can post a new question with the errors you are getting.)

Comment: In the graph just above, given a `source` and a `sink` we derive the subgraph from source to sink. Can we give different color to `source` (red) and `sink` (green) vertices to clearly show the starting and ending vertices?

Comment: @TugrulTemel, please see the update.

Comment: Thank you so much...

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I could do to answer my own question:

```
ClearAll[n, matA, matB, map];
<< IGraphM`;
<< BoolEval`;
SeedRandom[4];
n = 10;
matA = RandomReal[{0.1, 0.5}, {n, n}];
matB = RandomReal[{0.1, 0.5}, {n, n}];

map[matrixA_?MatrixQ, matrixB_?MatrixQ, lb_Real, ub_Real] := 
    Module[{matA = matrixA, matB = matrixB, t1 = lb, t2 = ub, 
    subgraphBetween, pindex, prule, paths},
    subgraphBetween[t1, t2] := 
    AdjacencyGraph[BoolEval[t1 <= matA < t2], VertexLabels -> "Name"];
    pindex = FindPath[subgraphBetween[t1, t2], 4, 6, Infinity, All];
    prule = DeleteDuplicates[
       Flatten@Table[  
         Rule @@@ Partition[pindex[[i]], 2, 1], {i, Length[pindex]}  ]];
    paths = Graph[prule, EdgeWeight -> Take[Flatten@matB, Length[prule]], 
       VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"]
    ]

   map[matA, matB, 0.2, 0.3]
```

Although this partially answers my question, it is not so elegant. Partial because the respective elements from `matB` are not selected. I just selected an equal number of edge weights to have a working `code`. The correct selection of cells from `matB` should match with the edges in `prule`.